# How to make a Google Group a Super Admin of my Cloud Identity

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-cloud-identity

I get the error "Groups are not allowed to be added to this role." when I try to add a Google Group in my Cloud Identity domain as a Super Admin (through admin.google.com).

Is there anyway to provide super admin roles to a group of users rather than on individual users?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not really sure if it is possible, but it is written in this [post from support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986) that the recommended super user should only be 2 individual user and having more that 3 super user limits all your administrators' options for password recovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basically you cannot create a Super Admin group**, and there is a reason:

> ***Super admin accounts have irrevocable administrative permissions*** that
>   we do not recommended using in the day-to-day administration of your
>   organization.

Indeed, this does not really fit with a group-based policy.
Super admin accounts must be managed with direct ownership and countable.

The best practice advised by Google is the one as follows:

> Create a new email address that is not specific to a particular user
>   as the G Suite or Cloud Identity super admin account. This account
>   should be further secured with multi-factor authentication, and could
>   be used as an emergency recovery tool.

---

*Disclaimer: Comments and opinions are my own and not the views of my employer.*